# How to exclude "<? ... ?>" fragments in php code (gulp-htmlmin)?

Tags: regex, gulp

To ignore php code in gulp-htmlmin I use 
`ignoreCustomFragments: [/<\?(php|=)[\s\S]*?(?:\?>|$)/]`

But in my php code there is a string which contains the following fragment - "<?xml ... ?>". This string gives a mistake of gulp-htmlmin. I think it is because the string has "?>" which "closes" php code before its actual end.
How to set regex of `ignoreCustomFragments` to avoid the mistake?

Comment: this should not be caught, because `php|=` does not match `xml`.

Comment: i think "xml" doesn't matter. "?>" (a part of <?xml ...) - this string "closes" my php code and gulp-preprocess fills embarrassed

Comment: What is the input string? What is the regex you use? What is the expected result?

Comment: **input string(s)** are files with html and php code. **regex** - /<\?(php|=)[\s\S]*?(?:\?>|$)/ . **expected result** - gulp-htmlmin minify my html and ignore my php code, even if php code has "?>" strings, which make gulp-htmlmin "close" php code before its actual end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```perl
/
<\?(php|=)
(?:
  # match any symbol except ? or ' or "
  [^?'"]
  # or ? not followed by >
  | \?(?!>)
  # or match '...' substring
  | '(?:
        # match any symbol except '
        [^']
        # or ' preceded by \
        | (?<=\\)'
     )*'
  # or match "..." substring
  | "(?: [^"] | (?<=\\)" )*"
)*
(?:\?>|$)
/gmx
```

---

**Update**

For handling comments:

```perl
<\?(php|=)
(?:
  # match any symbol except ? or ' or " or /
  [^?'"\/]
  # or ? not followed by >
  | \? (?!>)
  # or / not followed by [*/]
  | \/ (?![*\/])
  # or match comment //
  | \/\/ [^\r\n]+
  # or match comment /* */
  | \/\* (?: [^*] | \*(?!\/) )+ \*\/
  # or match '...' substring
  | '(?:
        # match any symbol except '
        [^']
        # or ' preceded by \
        | (?<=\\)'
     )*'
  # or match "..." substring
  | "(?: [^"] | (?<=\\)" )*"
)*
(?:\?>|$)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your regex helped me when I deleted "gmx" in the end. As i understood your regex eliminates strings in php code. But what if "<? ... ?>" will encounter for example in comments?

Comment: Comments should be handled also, see update.